# export let async function with params

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a function like this:

```
let findOne = async function() {
    return "hello"
}

module.exports = findOne()
```

I get to export it and use it in another script easily like this:

```
const findOne =  require('../public/javascripts/data')
findOne.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
  })
```

Now I would like to do the same with another function in the same script as the first one but this time I would like it to have parameters:

```
let deleteOne = async function (id) {
   return id+10
}
module.exports = deleteOne()
```

In other script :

```
const deleteOne =  require('../public/javascripts/data')
deleteOne(5).then(function (result) {
   console.log(result)
})
```

How I can do that ?

Comment: Remove the brackets after “deleteOne” that is being passed to “module.exports”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have both functions in one file and export them you can do it like this

Export File:

```
let findOne = async function() {
    return "hello"
}

let deleteOne = async function (id) {
   return id+10
}

module.exports = {findOne, deleteOne}
```

in other Script:

```
const {findOne, deleteOne} =  require('../public/javascripts/data')

findOne().then(function (result) {
console.log(result)
})

deleteOne(5).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your export is wrong.
What you have is

`module.exports = findOne()` - This will call the function and export the result, which is a Promise.

To export the function itself, don't call it:
`module.exports = findeOne`

To export multiple functions in the same script, give them a name in the export (export an object that contains the functions):

```
module.exports = { findOne, deleteOne };
```

And import them with their name:

```
const { findOne } = require('<path>')
```

Comment: That’s fine for `findOne`, but not for `deleteOne`

Comment: It's the same issue in the deleteOne, at least in the code OP posted.

Answer (score 0):

You have exported as,

```
module.exports = deleteOne();
```

By assigning as above, you are exporting the value returned from executing the function. You should export only function reference as below.

```
module.exports = deleteOne;
```

Corrected code:
Exporting deleteOne:

```
let deleteOne = async function (id) {
   return id+10
}
module.exports = deleteOne;
```

Importing deleteOne:

```
const deleteOne =  require('../public/javascripts/data')
deleteOne(5).then(function (result) {
   console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: This will not work, as the OP said both functions are in the same script.
so module.exports needs to export an object containing the functions, not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just export the variable, in this case a function.

Example with commonJS

`index.js`

```
let findOne = async function() {
    return 'Hello';
}

let deleteOne = async function(id) {
    return id;
}

module.exports = {
    findOne,
    deleteOne,
}
```

`test.js`

```
const { findOne, deleteOne } = require('./index.js');

async function test() {
    const x = await findOne();
    const y = await deleteOne(5);
    console.log(x, y);
}

test();
```